# First android application.. need help in debgging

Tags: java, android, debugging

I am new to android and i'm stuck with my first application since 4 days. I tried following every post on android debugging, but was not helpful.

So this is my java code.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class Example extends Activity {
    TextView display;
    int count;
    Button k,j;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        display=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.t1);
        k=(Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
        j=(Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.opencv_tracker);
        k.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                count++;
                display.setText("YOUR TOTAL IS "+count);
            }
        });
        j.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                count--;
                display.setText("YOUR TOTAL IS "+count);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My Activity.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/t1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="YOUR TOTAL IS 0"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/add"
        android:textSize="25sp"/>

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/b2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Hal"
        android:textSize="25sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and the logcat returns an NPE error.

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 1228): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I am following The New Boston tutorials. What the app is trying to do, is simple addition and subtraction by one. And showing the total result.

Comment: so WHERE is this exception occuring? the backtrace should tell you.

Comment: You using Eclipse or Android Studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

these code :

```
display=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.t1);
    k=(Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
    j=(Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);
```

put it after this code :

```
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.opencv_tracker);
```

the NPE is mostly on the setOnClickListener since these k and j not init